# Is it possible to call c# scripts from MATLAB?

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a script in MATLAB that writes a CSV, the CSV is read by a c# script which writes a few more CSVs that I go back and read in MATLAB.

Is there any way to automate this so I don't have to call the c# code by hand each time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a C# script? A .csx file? A library? An executable? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to call into .net from Matlab.  The official documentation is at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/load-a-global-net-assembly.html  You should be aware that Matlab is case-sensitive (even when it comes to specifying the assembly path) and that it is also limited in the kinds of objects it can pass back and forth across the boundary.

If you pass an array into your C# dll from Matlab, it will appear to be an array of bare objects rather than an array of numbers.  In Matlab, you may need to use the char and cell methods to convert strings and arrays back into the form you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, e.g. "Is it possible to call C# functions from MATLAB": yes, it is. Mathworks provides decent documentation on [calling .NET assemblies from MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/using-net-libraries-in-matlab.html) on their website. Of course, there are limitations and some awkward quirks to take into account but basically you can create instances of .NET classes and interact with .NET applications from MATLAB.

To advise on automating this process, you could perhaps dive into the [MATLAB COM Automation Service](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html)?

In the extension of this: it's also possible to call [MATLAB functions in a .NET application](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-a-c-client.html). The other way around, sort of speak. This will be no problem with basic data types, but when it gets a bit more advances it can put you through some gnarly COM challenges, though.